# Aborted request unless fiddler is running for only some users

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, fiddler

I have a really weird problem with my ASP.NET app where on only 2 users out of dozens using my intranet app it aborts the request. I have windows authentication turned on but I allow all users. Additionally there is no response code in the IE11 network tab it only shows "(Aborted)".

Also, it suddenly works whenever I have fiddler open. I've read this [article](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-) and I do indeed use WebRequest and I wasn't closing the connection. However I've changed it to close both the stream and the response object but it still doesn't work. Furthermore I've commented out this part of my code entirely and it still doesn't work. I've also restarted the app pool and restarted the server with no effect.

Not sure how to debug this since it works when fiddler is open which I was trying to use to debug it.

[image: cant displayed error message]

**EDIT 1**

I forgot to add my app was working yesterday for these users and I haven't done anything since then.

**EDIT 2**

Here are the proxy settings for IE. The blacked out box contains a path to a configuration script that our company uses. I added this because of the comments but I'm not entirely sure what a proxy even is.

[image]

**EDIT 3**

Ok so I tried deploying to a different server and it works on the new server. -_-

**EDIT 4**

I reinstalled ISS on the old server and it worked until I enabled windows authentication and disabled anoymonous authentication. However the new server works with windows authentication. If I enable windows authentication and anomonyous authentication on the old server it also works.

Comment: Fiddler registers itself as the current proxy for IE, and unregisters itself on exit. If Fiddler fails to exit gracefully for a reason or another, IE will still try talking to it even if it no longer runs. Double-check your users' proxy settings.

Comment: I don't know enough about proxies to know what you're talking about. What does "Could be a proxy" mean? How do I double check my users' proxy settings?

Comment: On IE, Internet Options > Connections tab > LAN Settings button > Proxy Server frame.

Comment: ok but I don't get what you're saying to do?